# How to unit test a callback in node.js using sinon, when callback is not passed as parameter?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

```
var data = function (req, res, next) {
    var data;
    modelClass.getData(function (err, response) {
            data = response[0];
            req.headers[constants.DATA] = data;
            next();
        }
    });
};
```

How would I unit test the above function, in Node.js (express.js) especially when callback is not passed in as parameter? I plan to use the Sinon unit test framework.

The examples shown here: [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qlmv7nox5pM) only shows how to test when call back is passed as parameter.

Comment: The question is a little broad since you can test several different aspects of this. It shouldn't be too bad thought since you can pass your own `next()` and `req` in.

Answer (score 2):

Basically we can do some checking in the unit test:

1. check if `req.headers[constants.DATA]` has correct value
2. check if `next` is called

Here is an example of mine to test that code

```
const chai = require('chai');
const assert = chai.assert;
const sinon = require('sinon');

const modelClass = require('...'); // your model class file
const src = require('...'); // your source file

describe('test', function() {
  let req;
  let res;
  let next;
  const response = [100];

  beforeEach(function() {
    // we mock `req` and `next` here
    req = {
      headers: {}
    };
    next = sinon.spy();
    sinon.stub(modelClass, 'getData').yields(null, response); // for callback function, we use yields to trigger the callback
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    sinon.restore();
  })

  it('run successfully', function() {    
    src.data(req, res, next);

    assert.equal(req.headers[constants.DATA], 100);  
    assert(next.calledOnce);  
  });
});
```